# HTML Generator, Gallery Generator or Templating?

Tags: python, html, templating-engine

**SMALL VERSION OF THE QUESTION**: " I need a lib for python or program (pref. for Linux) that receives a list of urls for images and gives me the hmtl for a table (maybe easy to configure(rows and look))

**LONG VERSION OF THE QUESTION**:
I have and array with a **list of url's** for images, and I want to make a **table** (I don't know if this is the best practice, but I think it's the easiest).
I don't care if the thumbs are the same file as the big one (just forced to be small). And I don't need to copy the images to anywhere.

I use the following code( d= ["http://.....jpg","http://.....jpg","http://.....jpg","http://.....jpg"]):

```
def  stupidtable(d):
    d = list(set(d))
    antes=' <tr> <td><a href="'
    dp11='"><img src="'
    dp12= '" width="100%" /></a></td> <td><a href="'
    dp21= '"><img src="'
    dp22='" width="100%" /></a></td>'
    bb=['<table border="0"> ']
    ii=len( d)
    i=0
    while i<ii-1:
        bb.append(antes)
        bb.append(d[i])
        bb.append(dp11)
        bb.append(d[i])
        bb.append(dp12)
        bb.append(d[i+1])    
        bb.append(dp21)
        bb.append(d[i+1])
        bb.append(dp22)
        i=i+2
    return bb
```

(I know the code is shady and it skips the last one if it's an odd number... but it's caffeine fueled code and I just needed to get it done... nothing I'm proud of:) 
I know there must be a better way(and prettier.. 'cus this looks really ugly), and a way that I can specify the number of columns, and other options.

I couldn't find a gallery generator for my case (all I tested copied the files to new directory).
Should I learn a **templating lang**? Is it worth it?

Or Should I use an **HTML Generator**?

Or should I look into better coding HTML?

**What Would you do if you had my problem?**

This is the solution I came up with (after adpting the code from kind Mr MatToufoutu):

```
from jinja2 import Template

my_template = Template("""
<html>
<style type="text/css">
   img {border: none;}
</style>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0">
<tr>
{% for url in urls %}
<td><a href="{{ url }}"><img width="100%" src="{{ url }}"/></td>
{% if loop.index is divisibleby cols %}
</tr><tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
""")

cols=3
urls =["./a.jpg","./a.jpg","./a.jpg","./a.jpg","./a.jpg","./a.jpg","./a.jpg"]
html = my_template.render(cols=cols,urls=urls)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to use a template language like [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) or [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). Personally i'd choose Jinja, because it is very similar to the Django template language, but they are all very powerful.

A very simple example of what you want, using Jinja, would look like this:

```
from jinja2 import Template

my_template = Template("""
<html>
<body>
<table border="0">
<tr>
{% for url in urls %}
<td><a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
""")

urls = ["http://.....jpg","http://.....jpg","http://.....jpg","http://.....jpg"]
rendered_html = my_template.render(urls=urls)
```

Which is way more readable than building the html by hand like you did.

Comment: I'll try jinja2 tonight... But your example convinced me :)

Answer (score 0):

Spare a few minutes to learn a template engine like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). It really pays up, because you can focus on code and leave the layout to webdesigners.